# How to create PEM files containing RSA private/publickey

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, rsa

What are the standard ways of storing RSA private /public keys in files. How can we create these files.
Once these files are created, how can we read them using standard .NET Framework classes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What are the standard ways of storing RSA private /public keys in files.

RSA public keys are commonly stored as SubjectPublicKeyInfo ASN.1 objects, either in [DER or PEM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.690) format. Alternatively, they are often contained within an X509 certificate (again in DER or PEM format).

RSA private keys are commonly stored encrypted in [PKCS#8 files](http://www.rsa.com/rsalabs/node.asp?id=2130).

> How can we create these files.

OpenSSL can be used to produce RSA key pairs in the formats mentioned above. See Google for how to do this.

> Once these files are created, how can we read them using standard .NET Framework classes.

[Using a previously generated RSA public/private key with the .net framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528928/using-a-previously-generated-rsa-public-private-key-with-the-net-framework?rq=1)