# BouncyCastle Error Unable to cast object of type 'Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.DerSequence' to type 'Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.DerBitString

Tags: c#, encryption, casting, rsa, bouncycastle

i tried using the solution on [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37413837/c-sharp-rsa-encrypting-text-using-a-given-pkcs1-public-key) but with my public key but i get a casting error :

System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.DerSequence' to type 'Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.DerBitString'.'

```
        Asn1Object obj = Asn1Object.FromByteArray(Convert.FromBase64String(privateKey));
        DerSequence publicKeySequence = (DerSequence)obj;
        //string testText = publicKeySequence[2].ToString();
        //publicKeySequence[1].GetDerEncoded();
        DerBitString encodedPublicKey = (DerBitString)publicKeySequence[1];
        DerSequence publicKey = (DerSequence)Asn1Object.FromByteArray(encodedPublicKey.GetBytes());

        DerInteger modulus = (DerInteger)publicKey[0];
        DerInteger exponent = (DerInteger)publicKey[1];
```

May somebody help on where i am getting this wrong and how to correct it.

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Hi Lasse, i have included the code on edit. 

i am getting an error on this line:

DerBitString encodedPublicKey = (DerBitString)publicKeySequence[1];

Comment: You have a string variable named `privateKey`, but your using code designed to parse an SPKI public key. So what do you have, a public key or a private key. And what format is the key in? The answer you link to fails to note that it's actually working with an SPKI-formatted public key, where the PKCS#1 public key is encoded as a bit string.